# Windows terminal: open multiple panes and execute specified command

Tags: command, execute, launch, pane, windows-terminal

I recently downloaded the new `Windows Terminal`. I have created the shortcut for opening the multiple panes(which is working fine). However, I am trying to execute a command for the respective pane.

```sh
wt -d <path> -c "cls && php artisan serve" ; 
   split-pane -p "Command Prompt" -H -d <path> -c "npm run watch"
```

I googled for the solution but no luck.

Is this even possible..?

Comment: Some interesting ideas [here](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/5528).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got a similar setup working.
Im running Windows Terminal version 1.8.1444.0

My goal was to setup a dotnet core app running in left pane and a react-app running in right pane:

```
wt -d "C:\path\to\dotnetcoreapp" -p "Command Promt" cmd /k dotnet watch run ; split-pane -d "C:\path\to\reactapp" cmd /k yarn start
```

Also tried to start an interactive elixir session: `wt -d "C:\dev\elixir" cmd /k IEx` which also worked fine...

Answer (score 8):

The short answer is: *Yes it is possible but it is a workaround.*

**The Challenges**

1. `wt.exe` does not currently have a command line option to execute a
   command from a `split-pane`
2. `wsl.exe` (which runs your default shell such as bash) does not currently support opening a shell with a command without exiting the shell right after the command is run.

**The workaround**

To get around the first challenge we can launch a custom profile that executes the command via `wsl.exe` in the key value pair (in settings json) `"commandline": "wsl.exe 'commands go here"`

To get around the second challenge we need to execute the `wsl.exe 'commands go here'` via `powershell.exe` because Powershell has a `-NoExit` option which will keep the shell open after the command is executed. So for example if you wanted to open a shell that runs `wsl.exe` (your linux shell) with the command `watch ps` then the line in the custom profile would look like this:

`"commandline": "powershell.exe -NoExit -Command wsl.exe watch ps"`

**The Solution:**

Create a profile in Windows Terminal `settings.json` for each command you want to run. Each profile should have a unique `guid` that you can generate in Powershell by running the command `[guid]::NewGuid()`. So the profile to run the command `watch ps` would look something like this:

```json
{
    "guid": "{b7041a85-5613-43c0-be35-92d19002404f}",
    "name": "watch_ps",
    "commandline": "powershell.exe -NoExit -Command wsl.exe watch ps",
    "hidden": false,
    "colorScheme": "One Half Dark"
},
```

Now you can open a tab in windows terminal with two panes, the pane on the right will run the command `watch ps` and the shell will stay open. Put something like the below line of code in your shortcut (or from the command line) where the value of the option `-p` is equal to the value of the profile you created. Each additional pane you open will need a profile that has the command you want to run in it.

`wt split-pane -p "watch_ps"`